# How can I add QtCharts library to my project?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, charts, qtcharts

I was trying to add QtCharts library to my project but an error occurred:

```
Target "PTP3" links to target "Qt6::Charts" but the target was not found. Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

I installed Qt5::Charts and Qt6::Charts via Qt MaintenanceTool but the issue remained. Anyone knows how to fix it?

I'm using Qt Creator 7.0.2. Here is my Cmake file. I followed the instructions from https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcharts-index.html but it didn't help.:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(PTP3 VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Charts REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        footballmatches.cpp
        footballmatches.h
        footballmatches.ui
        pivottable.h
        pivottable.cpp
        pivottable.ui
        stadiumschart.h
        stadiumschart.cpp
        stadiumschart.ui
        some_qml.qml
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(PTP3
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET PTP3 APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(PTP3 SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(PTP3
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(PTP3 PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(PTP3 PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Charts)

set_target_properties(PTP3 PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(PTP3)
endif()
```

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it. I cant work and test the CMake File that you add.

Answer (score 0):

you should have both these lines in your Cmake File for adding one of the qt libs to your project for example for qt charts you need these:

```
find_package(Qt5Charts REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}

     Qt5::Charts

)
```

**Be sure to add  `target_link_libraries` at the end of your `CMakeLists.txt` file.**

Comment: Thank you. I did as you said, but CMake thrown another error: `The keyword signature for target_link_libraries has already been used with the target "PTP3".  All uses of target_link_libraries with a target must be either all-keyword or all-plain. The uses of the keyword signature are here: * /Users/mikhail_ovakimyan/Qt/6.2.3/macos/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:524 (target_link_libraries) * CMakeLists.txt:56 (target_link_libraries)`. What do I do from here?

Comment: @MichaelOvakimian I can't say, because I don't know what you do in your project. provide a simple example in your question which is usable. Please clarify the question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.